# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: when creating presized Bitmaps for a RecyclerView using BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-recyclerview

Firstly, I understand questions regarding `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` and Bitmaps have already been asked numerous times before. I have also checked out the  [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) page.

**My use case:**

I am storing two different sized bitmaps as Strings in an SQLite database. The first size of the Bitmaps is 50% of the screen width, and the second size is 100% of the screen width.

I am using a RecyclerView which displays the images in ImageViews which are either 50% or 100% of the screen width, so the Bitmaps being loaded **are no bigger than they need to be, and they are appropriately sized before the images are retrieved from the Database.**

I am also loading the Bitmaps using an AsyncTask.

I have 12 different items in the RecyclerView so I have a total of 24 Bitmaps (12 images in 2 sizes) being created via this code:  `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);`

**The Problem**

The Activity loads without the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, unless I restart the same Activity around 5 times in a row (e.g. load the Activity, then recreate the Activity by clicking on it again in the Navigation Drawer and then repeating that process).

**A possible solution**

If I recycle the bitmaps in the onPause life cycle event like this:

```
public void recycleBitmaps(){
    int howManyBitmaps = bitmapsFullScreenWidth.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < howManyBitmaps; i++) {
        if (recyclerAdapter.bitmapsHalfScreenWidthArrayList.get(i) != null && !recyclerAdapter.bitmapsHalfScreenWidthArrayList.get(i).isRecycled()) {
            recyclerAdapter.bitmapsHalfScreenWidthArrayList.get(i).recycle();
            recyclerAdapter.bitmapsHalfScreenWidthArrayList.remove(i);
            recyclerAdapter.bitmapsHalfScreenWidthArrayList.add(i, null);
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < howManyBitmaps; i++) {
        if (recyclerAdapter.bitmapsFullScreenWidth.get(i) != null && !  recyclerAdapter.bitmapsFullScreenWidth.get(i).isRecycled()) {
            recyclerAdapter.bitmapsFullScreenWidth.get(i).recycle();
            recyclerAdapter.bitmapsFullScreenWidth.remove(i);
            recyclerAdapter.bitmapsFullScreenWidth.add(i, null);
        }

    }
}
```

Then the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` doesn't occur but I have to initialise the RecylerView's adapter in `onResume()` in order to avoid the `Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.` error and this means that if the user leaves the app whilst in this Activity the Adapter has to be reinitialised once they reenter that activity, and it could be preferable to solve the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` without recycling the bitmaps everytime onPause() is called.

I am reluctant to cache the Bitmaps as this could, for example, make the rest of the Activity perform less smoothly.

**My Question in a nutshell**

If my Activity is able to load the Bitmaps successfully without crashing as a result of the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError until I restart the Activity multiple then what is the best way of avoiding the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` when my Activity is restarted multiple times?

Thanks in advance

**Edit** The Glide library is able to solve the OOM issue here but it results in some of the RecyclerView's images disappearing as the RecyvlerView scrolls, although, they are reloaded - but that might be solvable

Comment: From what you are saying it sounds like you are actually setting new bitmaps and the old ones are still in memory. I'm not entirely sure why you are reluctant to cache Bitmaps. There really is no other way. There won't be performance issues if you show a loading image as the bitmaps are being decoded from the cache if necessary. Anyways, I hope you are using a library. This problem is solved fairly well if you use Universal Image Loader or Picasso.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think that the Universal Image Loader or Picasso are able to load byte arrays, if I could use one of them to do that then I would. It says [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)  that you cache "bitmaps at the cost of taking up valuable application memory", but, if it won't effect the performance of animations I have in that Activity then I might cache the bitmaps if there isn't a simpler way to avoid the OOM error